# Kendo Treeview error: Request Failed C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I've tried to built a **Kendo Treeview** linked to a **List** in **C#** and **ASP.NET MVC**, but each time I run the Application it displays instead of the **List** I get a **Request Failed** error.

My C# code
The Controller:

```
public JsonResult RetrieveData()
{            
    var testList = new List<AssetsVM>();

    var root = new AssetsVM { id = 1 , name = "Elsman" };
    testList.Add(root);

    root.Children.Add(new AssetsVM { id = 2, name = "Elsman1" });
    root.Children.Add(new AssetsVM { id = 3, name = "Elsman2" });

    return Json(testList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the List code
The View Model

```
 public class AssetsVM
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<AssetsVM> Children { get; set; }
    public AssetsVM()
    {
        this.Children = new List<AssetsVM>();
    }

    public AssetsVM(tbl_Assets x)
    {
        this.name = x.Name;
        this.id = x.ID;
        this.Children = new List<AssetsVM>();
    }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return Children.Any(); }
    }
}
```

The HTML/Kendo Code
The View:

```
<div class="kendo-tree">
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeViewDatabase")
        .DataTextField("name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Model(m => m
                .Id("id")
                .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                )
            .Read(read => read.Action("RetrieveData", "BeheerController"))
            )
        //.Events(e => e.Select("Index"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "color:white;"})
    )
</div>
```

Does anyone see the problem why I get a "Request Failed" Error?

Thanks in Advance

PS. The Table is not in use during the code but its already there for preporations

Comment: DO you really have a controller named `BeheerControllerController`?

Comment: You've read it wrong, it only says BeheerController

Comment: No, you have it wrong. If its `BeheerController` then it needs to be `.Action("RetrieveData", "Beheer"))`

Comment: The name of the class is "BeheerController " so that has to be in the .Action right?

Comment: No. Read my last comment.

Comment: ooh wait now I understand. It pastes automaticly  Controller behind your class name, right? cuz then it makes sense